# Ubuntu 20.04 install on hp pavilion 14-ce3501sa Not Working

Tags: dual-boot, 20.04, hp

Recently purchased a hp pavilion 14-ce3501sa with windows 10 and tried to dual boot install with ubuntu 20.04 but doesn't seem to work. It gets through the whole installation process from a live usb all the way through to "installation complete, please restart your computer" but when I restart it continues to boot into Windows and when I press F9 to load up the boot menu it shows me windows os loader and 'boot from efi file' and when I enter this it allows me to traverse to a folder called ubuntu but I cannot seem to boot it up. Would like to be able to even go into F9 and boot up ubuntu like that, That would be fine, anything at all

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I can solve this. But Iam giving a try. Sorry if its wrong.
Please press escape while booting. You may see the grub menu from there.
If you see it there will be option for ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Dhyansaj, I had done that previously and my ubuntu was just not booting/working, tried Ubuntu 18.04 on this tutorial and it worked perfectly! https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.itzgeek.com/amp/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot.html

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 could not be installed. I installed Ubuntu 18.04 through this tutorial from [itzgeek.com](https://www.itzgeek.com/) instead: [How to Install Ubuntu 18.04 Alongside With Windows 10 or 8 in Dual Boot](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.itzgeek.com/amp/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-ubuntu-18-04-alongside-with-windows-10-or-8-in-dual-boot.html)